# How should I make this website responsive?

Tags: html, css, web

So, I've been trying to make the header responsive as it should but it does not seem to work at all.
Any help would be nice.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<h2>This is just a test page that does not work on three tested devices any help would be nice.</h2>
</body>   
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enusure to add this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Yeah I also tried <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> before that. Seems like you shouldn't use decimals.

Answer (score -1):

You can use bootstrap head and it will do it for you.

```
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Bootstrap is amazing for creating websites: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp

Comment: I have used Bootstrap before but do not want to rely on Bootstrap. Bootstrap would be my last option. I just want to try things without Bootsrap.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> This line is in charge of scaling webpage.  For any containers you create, ensure to set width in procentage and not pixels

Comment: Yeah, I know but I haven't used a <div> tag. I also tried putting the <h2> tag into a div but it didn't work.

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` I used this and it works on any size of the screen. It resize it accordingly. ensure to add `initial-scale=1` in the end!